# TikZ vertical alignment of circled text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an issue with the vertical alignment of circled text with TikZ. This basic code causes the problem I have.

```
  \texttt{some text here =}
  \tikz[remember picture] \node[draw,ellipse,fill=none,thick] (code) {\texttt{other text}};
```

The problem is that the displayed text 'some text here=' is not vertically aligned with the displayed text 'other text'. I read about anchors in the documentation and they looked promising, but I've been unable to get them to work for me so far. Perhaps I could do this by making the left hand side a node, but I don't think that should be necessary? Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should add to the `\tikz` options `baseline=-0.825ex`: that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `base` of the node for the `baseline` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\texttt{some text here =}
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(code.base)] \node[draw,ellipse,fill=none,thick] (code) {\texttt{other text}};

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*Edited by Claudio Fiandrino*

This is a possible alternative:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\texttt{some text here = \tikz[baseline=-0.825ex] \node[draw,ellipse,fill=none,thick] (code) {other text};}
\end{document}
```

Notice that if you insert the `tikz` code inside the first `texttt` you can skip the command inside the node since it is automatically rendered in typewriter.

Comment: I've added the alternative present in my previous answer; hope you don't mind. `:)`

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino not at all. :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
 \texttt{some text here =}
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline] 
   \node[draw,ellipse,fill=none,thick,anchor=base] (code) {\texttt{other text}};
```